# Python: Sum NAs with relativedelta

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, relativedelta

I have 2 columns in a dataset of 327 records:

```
 #   Column                     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                     --------------  -----               
 0   JD                         327 non-null    datetime64[ns]       
 1   CD                         312 non-null    Int64
```

And I want to generate a third one (`['theoretical_eoc']`) that gives me the dates kept in `[JD]` plus a number of months specified in `[CD]`. But when I define this new column by using:

```
df['theoretical_eoc'] = turnover.apply(lambda x: x.JD + relativedelta(months=x.CD), axis=1)
```

I receive the following error message:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NAType'
```

So, I defined a function to put `NaT` in case one of the the values in any of the columns is a NA:

```
def rd_na(a, b):
    if pd.isnull(a) or pd.isnull(b):
        pd.NaT
    else:
        a + relativedelta(months = b)
```

But when I apply it:

```
df['theoretical_eoc'] = turnover.apply(lambda x: rd_na(x.JD, x.CD), axis=1)
```

The result is a column full of `None` values, when I was expecting `datetime64[ns]` with some `NaT`. What am I doing wrong? How could I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the returns in the `rd_na` function

```
def rd_na(a, b):
    if pd.isnull(a) or pd.isnull(b):
        return pd.NaT
    else:
        return a + relativedelta(months = b)
```

Consider using DateOffset from pandas as it handles `pd.NaT`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

df['theoretical_eoc'] = turnover.apply(lambda x: x.JD +
                                       DateOffset(months=x.CD), axis=1)
```